# Symfony 2.1 - FPNTagBundle - add a Tag bug?

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I have installed [FPNTagBundle](https://github.com/FabienPennequin/FPNTagBundle) via composer.

```
        $tagArray=array('uno','due');
        $tagManager = $this->get('fpn_tag.tag_manager');
        $tagsObj = $tagManager->loadOrCreateTags($tagArray);
        $tagManager->replaceTags($tagsObj,$entity);
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();
```

I get this error that avoid tag to persist:

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO Tag (name, slug,
>   created_at, updated_at) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)' with params
>   {"1":null,"2":"uno","3":null,"4":null}:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name'
>   cannot be null 500 Internal Server Error - DBALException

It's seems a problem calling    $tag = parent::createTag($name); in line35 of TagManager.php

Any ideas?
v.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? It happens for me too.

Comment: No. Aftermath I don't use this bundle.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue in my project.
The problem was that the Tag entity prevented the execution of the constructor in the `BaseTag` (`FPN\TagBundle\Entity\Tag`) class. I am pretty sure that your Tag class has its own constructor and you do not call the parent one, which sets the name attribute missing in your entity.

Here is an example custom Tag class which calls the parent constructor to set the name:

```
use FPN\TagBundle\Entity\Tag as BaseTag;

class Tag extends BaseTag
{
    protected $tagging;
    public function __construct($name = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($name);
        $this->tagging = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```